# Проблемы с логинизацией

Tags: jquery, javascript, html, php, bootstrap

Есть две формы:

```
 <form class="form-inline" id="reg-form" method="POST" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="registration()" >
              <legend class="cursor-default noselect">Регистрация</legend>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Введите логин:</label>
                <input type="text" name="login" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Логин">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Пароль</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Пароль">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Регистрация</button>
        </form>
```

и

```
        <form class="form-inline" id="login-form" method="POST" action="javascript:void(null);" onsubmit="sendlogin()">
              <legend class="cursor-default noselect">Вход</legend>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Логин:</label>
                <input type="text" name="login" class="form-control" maxlength="15" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Логин">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Пароль</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" maxlength="15"  class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Пароль">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Войти</button>
              <br>
              <p id = "reg-button">Регистрация</p>
        </form>
```

И два ajax запроса по ним:

```
function registration() {
      var reg   = $('#reg-form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'php/saveuser.php',
          data: reg,
          success: function(data) {
            alert('Регистрация прошла успешно');
          },
          error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
     };

    function sendlogin() {
      var logn   = $('#login-form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'php/testreg.php',
          data: logn,
          success: function(data) {
            $("#teststring").load("php/testreg.php");

           },
          error:  function(xhr, str){
                alert('Возникла ошибка: ' + xhr.responseCode);
            }
        });
     };
```

Проблема в том, что первая форма и скрипт работают. Вторая, как я понял, отправляет пустые значения. Кто знает, в чём может быть проблема?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['login'])) { $login = $_POST['login'];
if ($login == '') { unset($login);} }
if (isset($_POST['password'])) { $password=$_POST['password'];
if ($password =='') { unset($password);} }
if (empty($login) or empty($password)) 
{
exit ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");
}
$login = stripslashes($login);
$login = htmlspecialchars($login);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$password = htmlspecialchars($password);
$login = trim($login);
$password = trim($password);
?>
```

Этим оба запроса обрабатываются.

Comment: Хм, `логинизация`... И тут я понял, что формализовать проблему проще таки на английском

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогли мне разгадать эту загадку. Форма правильно всё отправляла в запрос, который я, в поиске ошибок, сократил до простой выдачи результатов через echo.

Собственно логика такая, что ajax запрос отправлял данные формы в php скрипт. Скрипт где-то себе выводил результат, потом по-новой, уже с пустыми значениями, грузился на страницу. 
Проблема была с:

```
$("#teststring").load("php/testreg.php");
```

Надо было писать:

```
 $("#teststring").html("php/testreg.php");
```

Comment: Почему не `$('#test').text(data);`? Что такое `$.http()` и зачем вообще делать второй запрос в php?

Comment: Писал-же что искал ошибку. Изначально были совсем другие цели и другой скрипт.
$('#test').text(data);  да, и так можно. Главное, что .load нельзя
    $.http() -  очевидно, еще одна ошибка. .html имелось ввиду.

Answer (score 0):

Вы написали, что они обрабатываются один php скриптом, но url у вас заданы разные, возможно, в этом проблема?

На всякий случай, формируется всё правильно: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncLqun96/1/)

Comment: Ясно, что в разные файлы форма обращается. Но те файлы инклудят один и тот же файл для проверки форм, который я и скинул сюда.
Проблема, это я написать забыл, выходит строкой: "Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!", а она присустствует только в этом скрипте и только на стадии проверки.